# Creating and executing a stored procedure in spring boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc

I have a stored procedure written in a sql file which I want to execute through spring boot code using jdbc template. The stored procedure is like :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DELETE_REDUNDANT_RECORDS()
RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
    interval_time            BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    min_time                 BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    max_time                 BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    rec_old                  RECORD;
    rec_new                  RECORD;
    rec_start                RECORD;
    v_filename               VARCHAR(250);
    v_systemuid              VARCHAR(50);
    is_continous_record      BOOLEAN default false;

    cursor_file CURSOR FOR
        select distinct filename,systemuid from ASP.MONITORING_BOOKMARK_ORIGINAL;
    cursor_data CURSOR FOR
        select * from ASP.MONITORING_BOOKMARK_ORIGINAL where filename = v_filename and systemuid=v_systemuid order by mindatetime, maxdatetime;

BEGIN
    --open the file cursor to fetch the filename and systemuid
    OPEN cursor_file;
    -- logic for procedure
    CLOSE cursor_file;
END;
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have added this in a sql file in my spring boot project. I want to create a scheduler to create and execute this stored procedure using spring jdbc. The database used is Postgres. Is there a way available to do this. I have got references for calling a procedure but what I need is to create and execute the procedure.

Comment: Put the code in a String, then run it using `Statement.execute(String)`

Comment: Can this be done using the jdbc template also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For running the procedure, Spring's [`SimpleJdbcCall`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html) could be what you are looking for.
Its use should be fairly straightforward:

1. create an instance supplying a `DataSource`
2. call `withCatalogName` and `withProcedureName` as needed
3. call `declareParameters` as needed
4. call `execute` to run the procedure

For creating it, a [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) and its own `execute` method should be sufficient.

Be aware that you might want to create the function once and only run it afterwards. Creating and running the procedure both as part of some scheduled operation is a quite uncommon requirement. You might want to re-assess the need to create the procedure each and every time if possible.